# Use LINQ to get only those items which is in List<>

Tags: c#, linq

I would assume there's a simple LINQ query to do this, I'm just not exactly sure how. Please see code snippet below, the comment explains what I'd like to do:

I have three tables

```
Course
   Id     Name
  ----   ------
    1     php
    2     joomla
    3     mysql  

MainCourse
  Id     CourseCode
 ----   -------------
  1       Foundation
  2       Diploma
  3       Professional

SubCourse
  Id  CourseId   MainCourseId  
 ---- --------- --------------   
   1     1             1
   2     1             2
   3     2             2
   4     1             3
   5     2             3
   6     3             3

  List<int> courseIdList={1,2}

//I would like to perform a LINQ query to give me 'CourseCode'
//from 'courseIdList' 
//this example should give me 'Diploma'
//CourseIdList could vary below are the expected results
//CourseIdList={1}  ==> CourseCode=Foundation(MainCourse)
//CourseIdList={1,2} ==> CourseCode=Diploma(MainCourse)
//CourseIdList={1,2,3} ==> CourseCode=Professional(MainCourse)

//Rule is that I want to get only those items from the subcourse
//where 'courseId(subcourse)' matches the 'courseIdList'

//Say CourseIdList={1,2},I need to omit the following Id (1,4,5,6)
//from subcourse since MainCourseId=1 , contains courseId =1 (not 1,2)
//and MainCourseId=3 , contains courseId = 1,2,3 (not 1,2)
```

Comment: This is not really clear. Why only IDs 2 and 3? What about the others with `CourseId` 1 or 2?

Comment: when you say LINQ, are you querying in-memory objects? or the database via an ORM? or...? (LINQ has many different implementations)

Comment: What do the items in `courseIdList` match up to in `SubCourse`? Are you matching on `MainCourseId`? Otherwise this doesn't make sense based on your expected output + input. Ok you've now edited your question and there is no mention of `SubCourse`? Anyway, why is the expected output now only `Diploma` and not `Foundation` and `Diploma` (1,2)?

Comment: @RenéVogt  Updated the question kindly check and let me know if you need any clarification,

Comment: Now it's even less clear. Why is "Diploma" the correct result? What are your rules for that?

Comment: Change structure of your table :  MainCourse(ID,Name) Course(ID,Name,MainCourseID).you don't need table subcourse

Comment: @RenéVogt updated the question and let me know if you need any clarification ?

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this by grouping `SubCourse` by the `MainCourseId`, then creating a list of the corresponding courses' IDs and comparing this list to your `courseIdList`.

A simple example:

```
var result = subCourses.GroupBy(sc => sc.MainCourseId).
               Where(g => g.Select(c => c.CourseId).SequenceEqual(courseIdList));
```

But note that `SequenceEquals` only works if the sequences are in the same order. So you'll need to enhance this `Where` clause a little to compare sequences that may be not in the same order.

If your `courseIdList` is always ordered, it would be enough to order that course Id sequence like this:

```
var result = subCourses.GroupBy(sc => sc.MainCourseId).
               Where(g => g.Select(c => c.CourseId).OrderBy(id => id).SequenceEqual(courseIdList));
```

---

The `result` you get is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<SubCourse>>`, containing all corresponding `MainCourses` that consist of the `Courses` referenced in your `courseIdList` (there may theoretically be more than one matching `MainCourse`).
The `Key` of the `IGrouping` is the `MainCourse.ID`.

Comment: Thanks mate.Will check that and give reply :)